# How to redirect not-existing link to Home page in Angular 2?

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

If user input a not-existing link, I want the page redirect to Home page.

How can I do it? Thanks

```
@RouteConfig([
    {path: '/home', name: 'Home', component: HomeComponent},
    {path: '/about', name: 'About', component: AboutComponent},
    {path: '/???', name: 'not-found', redirectTo: ['Home']}
])
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This will redirect all unregistered routes to Home

```
{ path: "/**", redirectTo: ["Home"] }
```

Comment: Not sure enough to edit the question directly, but my tslint is more happy without the brackets around "Home" :)

Comment: Angular v4+  use   path: '**'

Answer (score 1):

In Routing of the version v4 name property no more exist. route define without name property. so you should use path instead of name redirectTo: '/redirectPath' and no leading slash for path so use path: '404' instead of path: '/404'

like:

```
 {path: '404', component: NotFoundComponent},
 {path: '**', redirectTo: '/404'}
```