# Angular2 - can't redirectTo NotFound page

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I wanna redirect user to *Not found page* if user type error url. I saw this [post](http://blog.ng-book.com/basic-routing-in-angular-2/) and this [page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35529550/how-to-redirect-not-existing-link-to-home-page-in-angular-2) and try in own project. But when I enter somthing get error:

```
Invalid route configuration of route '/**': path cannot start with a slash
```

My *app.routing.ts*

```js
export const routes: Routes = [
    {
        path: 'home',
        component: AppComponent,
        children: [
            {
                path: '',
                component: LoginComponent
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        path: "/**",
        redirectTo: 'home',
        pathMatch: 'full'
    },
]
```

I wanna redirect to home page if all paths not matches with routes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change to following,

```
{
        path: "**",
        redirectTo: 'home',
        pathMatch: 'full'
},
```

Comment: As it solves the problem, please don't mind to accept answer. ;-)